# ORACLE APEX 5 - Master Detail Form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have developed a master - detail form with a master report.
I have a filter on the master Report which is successfully excluding rows as in they not displayed. So I have for example 5 out of 10 rows in table A displayed.

My problem is when I select a row, click on it, it navigates to the Master Detail Screen (the Master Region has navigation buttons) I get all rows, i.e. it says 1/10. Is there any way I can exclude the filtered out rows in Master Navigation?

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have already tried, and also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what your problem is.

It sounds like you have a report page and a form page - is that it? Not really a master-detail (like Department-Employees) but many Employees vs a single Employee?

If so Does the report page use page items to filter the rows? And does the form page have a process of type "Form Pagination" to step through rows?

If all my assumptions are correct, then you can make the rows you can page through in the form page match the report filter by setting the "Runtime Where Clause" property of the "Form Pagination" process to match the WHERE clause of the report page, and reference the report page's filter items e.g.

```
(:P1_DEPTNO is null or deptno = :P1_DEPTNO)
```

Comment: Hi Tony , Thanks for your reply - I have been holiday so sorry for the late response.

Comment: please my repose in the answers ... this isn't goin well :)

Comment: @RobCrockett The trouble is, the way APEX builds master-detail forms changes from version to version, so I can't easily replicate your issue.  If possible, you could create a copy of your application - simplified to the 2 pages in question - and upload it to a workspace on apex.oracle.com so that we can see it.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thanks fro your help - I seem to have managed what my users wanted with some behind the scenes PL.. But is there somewhere I can fire off some PL when they leave the screen .. ie click on another menu option? I want to do some tidy up PL

Comment: If that menu option submits the page you can.  If it redirects then you could only try to write a process on load of the target page that tidies up when appropriate - tricky!

Comment: I tried doing my update in the menu navigation condition of the home page...  but it fires every time I do anything on the pages ! if I could just get it to fire once - when I go into the screen or once after I would be a happy bunny... it's just a tidy up

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of "tidy up" you mean, but maybe you can so something like this: have an application item called `TIDY_UP_PAGE_42` (or whatever); on entry to page 42 set `TIDY_UP_PAGE_42` to 'Y'. Have an application process the fires on page load with condition `TIDY_UP_PAGE_42` = 'Y'. This process says `if :app_page_id != 42 then ...(tidy up code)...; :TIDY_UP_PAGE_42 := null;`

Comment: thanks for bearing with me - shared comps are new for me.. So I have created a App Item called ADDMATCHTIDYUP Scope Application.. I have created an App Process Run_MatchAddressTidyUp.. My PL/SQL code contains begin procedure_name end; The process point is On Demand: Run this application process when requested by a page process..Condition Type Request is contained within Expression 1...Expression 1 is AddMatchTidyUp = 'Y'...... How am I doing?

Comment: Process Point should be "on page load" not "on demand".  So on every page load APEX will check the process condition and if true, run the process.

Comment: ive got "On Load: Before Header (.."

Comment: That's the one I mean :-)

Comment: cool... so    (I am a pain sorry) .. you mentioned setting the app item on entry to the page?  I'm on my page in designer.. where do I do that pls?

Comment: You could just put the value 'Y' in the items' Default property.

Comment: Tony, You have been a tremendous education to me! I am going push so hard for some training in apex . The application process thing is working proper now. many thanks - Rob